# Coded UI Test Builder - "Last mouse action was not recorded" happened since windows update

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I was recording tests yesterday with no problems. As there was a windows update, I did an Update and Restart of my machine. Now I can't record any tests with the Coded UI Test Builder now. This is in a Coded UI Test project. I have tried to record actions that I recorded no problem yesterday and I can't record them.
After I click on anything, it will hang, the mouse action will happen about 20 seconds later and the Coded UI Test Builder will say "Last mouse action was not recorded". Whilst I am recording mouse movement is slow too, at best the cursor catches up a few seconds after the mouse was moved and at worst it does nothing then jumps about a minute after you moved the mouse.

It's all very bizarre and nothing else has changed, only the windows update. I am also not making any basic mistakes because I did have this working before the updated.

I have restarted my machine 3 times and there are no more windows updates.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If anyone else is having this issue, please go to the link below for the latest info from Microsoft. Upvote the question to add weight to it being resolved by Microsoft. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41788/coded-ui-builder-vs2017-will-not-record-any-mouse.html

Comment: Now fixed in Fall Creators Edition of Windows 10 according to a 7 Nov 2017 Update to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41788/coded-ui-builder-vs2017-will-not-record-any-mouse.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an update from Microsoft ...

"The windows team has acknowledged that this is a bug in the new WIndows 10 creators update. This would be fixed as a part of the next update."

The thread is https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41788/coded-ui-builder-vs2017-will-not-record-any-mouse.html.

This is the best answer we'll get I think so don't update and do stop any updates until the next windows 10 update or Downdate if you have updated and then don't update until the next win 10 update from MS. Personally, if downdating I am doing so on a machine with no internet connection as there can be security updates in any windows update.

Comment: And finally it is fixed in the normal branch of windows 10. Only took 6 months....

Answer (score 1):

'Downdating' Windows will work. 
I had the same issue after Windows 10 Creators update, downdated it to previous version and problem solved

Comment: OK, at least I'm not alone. So the message is if you are doing Recorded Coded UI tests or running MS Test Manager and recording tests there (same thing behind the scenes) then do no get the latest window 10 update. The problem is that windows 10 updates are very persistent and it will be applied when you restart and nag you endlessly to update. Bloomin Microsoft!

Comment: I agree that Donwdating did work. I was using VS2015 (latest update) so I tried VS2017 and that didn't work. I tried switching off some setting for recording actions all to no avail. On balance, I can't mark Downdating as the answer though because it's a temporary workaround and we need an answer that will work when the next update is out etc. The answer will be either something we can do to get the latest windows 10 version to work or a fix from Microsoft in either a Windows 10 update or Visual Studio and Test Manager update to fix the issue.

Comment: After this weekend's cyber attacks, it is a brave person who Downdates their windows. I would keep at the latest version or use Windows LTSB to get the latest security updates but not the latest features.

Comment: 'brave' maybe, 'foolish' no. The patch for the vulnerability was shipped two months ago. moreover what I downdated from was a feature update not a security one.

Comment: OK, that's good to know. I'm going to wait for MS to fix this nonetheless.